# What word am I?

Tags: riddle, word

**What word am I?**

My meaning is very simple,
I am three celestial bodies.

In a line but I ask why,
why do I say why three times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a

> [syzygy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygy_(astronomy))

and that word

> contains three "Y"s.